# postgresql data on secondary disk, automatic start fails with "not accessible or does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, startup

The OS is Ubuntu 20.04. I moved the data directory to a secondary disk. In the "Disks" utility, I clicked "Edit Mount Options", turned off "User Session Defaults", and specified a hard-coded Mount Point like `/mnt/database`, because by default it was mounted at something like `/media/[user name]/disk label`. "Mount at system startup" had been checked (unchanged from default).

Now, postgresql's automatic start at the system startup fails with a message like: "[data directory] is not accessible or does not exist". If I manually start it, by executing `sudo systemctl start postgresql` it starts fine. I suspect that the system tried to start postgresql before the secondary disk was automatically mounted. Is that so? If that is the case, how can I make it start after the secondary disk has been mounted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was the order.

Open the service file:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service
```

Add the disk's name at:

```
After=network.target mnt-[disk name].mount
```

If the disk name is "database", then it is `mnt-database.mount`. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/217951